# Foreign key is created incorrrectly using EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a few tables set up to create a many to many relationship, but one of them isn't setting up the foreign keys correctly.
As far as I can tell, they are setup the same as the other tables.

So, first I will show the working tables.
I have a **Question** and a **Group** model which both have a navigation property of **QuestionGroups**. The models look like this:

```
public class Question : IEntity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool MultipleChoice { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }

    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

And Group looks like this:

```
public class Group : IEntity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }

    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OutcomeGroup> Outcomes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionGroup> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

In my `OnModelCreating` method, I have this relationship set up:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>().ToTable("QuestionGroups").HasKey(m => new { m.QuestionId, m.GroupId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasMany(m => m.Groups).WithOne().HasForeignKey(m => m.QuestionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(m => m.Questions).WithOne().HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

If I look at my server explorer and edit the two foreign keys created, they look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionGroups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionGroups_Groups_GroupId] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([Id]);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionGroups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionGroups_Questions_QuestionId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Questions] ([Id]);
```

Which is correct.
Now comes the weird one.
I have another table called **Outcomes** which again has a many to many relationship with **Groups**.
An **Outcome** looks like this:

```
public class Outcome : IEntity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)] public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2083)] public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OutcomeTag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OutcomeGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

And I have set up the relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OutcomeGroup>().ToTable("OutcomeGroups").HasKey(m => new { m.OutcomeId, m.GroupId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(m => m.Outcomes).WithOne().HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<Outcome>().HasMany(m => m.Groups).WithOne().HasForeignKey(m => m.OutcomeId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Yet, when I look in my server explorer and examine the foreign keys created, they are like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OutcomeGroups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OutcomeGroups_Groups_OutcomeId] FOREIGN KEY ([OutcomeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([Id]);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OutcomeGroups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OutcomeGroups_Outcomes_OutcomeId] FOREIGN KEY ([OutcomeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Outcomes] ([Id]);
```

The second key is correct, but the first one is not.
Can anyone spot why?

Comment: what happens if you configure the FK relationship explicitly? skipping to configure the inverse navigation properties even if you have none is not always the best idea btw.

Comment: Why do you even create a model for the m to m tables? there is no need for a model here because you have no additional data in your  m to m table, or am I wrong with that?

Comment: I ran code above and it works correctly. I did not get any incorrect constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding navigation properties to the Join table classes like this:

```
public class OutcomeGroup
{
    public int OutcomeId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public Outcome Outcome { get; set; }
}
```

and then I changed the modelBuilder to this:

```
// Many to many
modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerTag>().HasOne(m => m.Answer).WithMany(m => m.Tags).HasForeignKey(m => m.AnswerId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerTag>().HasOne(m => m.Tag).WithMany(m => m.Answers).HasForeignKey(m => m.TagId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<OutcomeTag>().HasOne(m => m.Outcome).WithMany(m => m.Tags).HasForeignKey(m => m.OutcomeId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<OutcomeTag>().HasOne(m => m.Tag).WithMany(m => m.Outcomes).HasForeignKey(m => m.TagId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<OutcomeGroup>().HasOne(m => m.Outcome).WithMany(m => m.Groups).HasForeignKey(m => m.OutcomeId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<OutcomeGroup>().HasOne(m => m.Group).WithMany(m => m.Outcomes).HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>().HasOne(m => m.Question).WithMany(m => m.Groups).HasForeignKey(m => m.QuestionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>().HasOne(m => m.Group).WithMany(m => m.Questions).HasForeignKey(m => m.GroupId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

And that worked.